# Reloading changed text file into JSP page using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

Need advice. I need to develop a largely static HTML page(s). However, the page needs to include a small portion of data which needs to be updated once a week or so. This update of data will be done by a non-technical person.

My solution was to create a JSP page and load the small portion of text using JSTL. I do not want to use servlets or struts as the page update is not frequent.

Code is as follows -:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Testing</h2>

    This is the container which will contain the user defined data ... 

    User defined data needs to be uploaded whenever the file changes.

    <h4 id="test"> Registration Information</h4>
    <c:import var="testHtml" url="content/LatestNews.html" />
    <c:out value="${testHtml}" escapeXml="false" />

</body>
</html>
```

My questions now are as follows -:

1. Is this a good solution or is there a better way to do this?
2. How do I make the final page reload the changes done to the text file (whenever the html/txt file updates)?

Comment: For  **How do I make the final page reload** - for a fresh request, wouldn't most upto date html ( of LatestNews.html ) be always loaded in your code snippet or am I missing something?Why folks ( End users ) can't refresh their page once for such a low frequency update?

Comment: I tried refreshing at the client side but it is not refreshing, thus I assumed I am missing something.

Comment: Refreshing do es refresh is what you have asked for? Or you want to refresh automatically?

Answer (score 0):

1.) If I'm not mistaken, if you have something to trigger the upload process from the end user, (button or etc) you need set the id.
Then using javascripts to control the reload time.

> Javascript

```
$('#triggerButton').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);
});
```

2.) If not and all the code is stated on the html you posted, you can always set a timeInterval to reload the page.
Something like

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 3000);
```

The first simple example displays a pop-up alert window every 3 seconds and the second reloads the page after 3 seconds. Credit to @aphextwix

> If the above still do not suite into your condition, then you might need to work around with the code using javascript as well. Something like this.

```
function myReloadNTimeOutFunction()
{
    doStuff();
    setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 1000);
}

myReloadNTimeOutFunction();
```

Hope it help. :)